# Launch batch script before windows login window

Tags: windows, batch-file, startup

I'm working on Windows Server 2003 and Windows server 2008.
I would like to start a batch script just before the login window is displayed.
I read about adding the script in the Group Policy editor (startup/shutdown) but it's not working (it worked for logon and logoff though).

An alternative would be to use the task scheduler service but it's not working either. Plus, I want to be able to see the results in a cmd window. That means the last alternative - creating a service to do the job - is not an option.

Do you have any idea ?

Thanks.

Comment: Try http://brattex.blogspot.com/2010/08/autoexnt-running-batch-file-before.html

Answer (score 2):

Control Panel -> Scheduled Tasks -> < follow the prompts>

Not as nice as a service, which you can start and stop through well-behaved commands, but if it is a service you want running at all times, it does the job.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding your script as a user defined service

That way it will get executed before the login prompt;

http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?kbid=137890

Though this article says it can't be used for batch scripts, you can call the script from an executable.